# Getting issue Upgrading from Mongo driver version 3.8.1 to 4.6.1

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongo-java-driver

After updating the mongo driver version from 3.8.1 to 4.6.1. I am getting below error in my existing queries

```
"Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$and'"
```

All the aggregations were working Earlier.
Spring boot version - 2.7.10
Java version - 11

If I revert the version from 4.6.1 to 3.8.1, I get class not defined error. Pls help me in resolving this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the Match Pipeline , it was adding and two times but it was working fine in previous version biut breaking when we were using the new verison. I modified the below code :
Instead of this

```
pipeline.add(and
```

Use this:

```
pipeline.addAll
```